# When connecting caravel to hive server, throws error when loading a table

Tags: sqlalchemy, hive

```
2016-07-06 19:39:09,153:ERROR:root:Compiler <sqlalchemy.sql.compiler.GenericTypeCompiler object at 0x10c75d150> can't render element of type <class 'impala.sqlalchemy.STRING'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user_name/.virtualenvs/caravel27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caravel/models.py", line 771, in fetch_metadata
    datatype = "{}".format(col.type).upper()
  File "/Users/user_name/.virtualenvs/caravel27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 481, in __str__
    return unicode(self.compile()).\
  File "/Users/user_name/.virtualenvs/caravel27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 468, in compile
    return dialect.type_compiler.process(self)
  File "/Users/user_name/.virtualenvs/caravel27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 261, in process
    return type_._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw)
  File "/Users/user_name/.virtualenvs/caravel27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 79, in _compiler_dispatch
    raise exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(visitor, cls)
```

Similar issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/71).

However I do not know how to pass `bind=engine` in case of using `sqlalchemy` via `caravel`

This is how you can replicate the error :

Install then run caravel using `caravel runserver -d`. Then add a hive2 database to caravel. To do this you need impyla. After installation use this as the sqlAlchemyURL `impala://somehostname.compute.amazonaws.com:10000/database_name?auth_mechanism=‌​PLAIN`. The test connection should return `Seems OK`. Caravel should also able to discover all the tables in database_name. However, when I add a table, caravel identifies all the columns as UNKNOWN type. Then look at the logs posted by caravel and the above mentioned error should be logged.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking for debugging questions. In other words, create a small example that produces the error.

Comment: I setup caravel using `caravel runserver -d`. Then I added a hive2 database, using impyla. This is the address I inserted in the sqlAlchemyURL `impala://somehostname.compute.amazonaws.com:10000/database_name?auth_mechanism=PLAIN`. The test connection returns `Seems OK`. Caravel is also able to discover all the tables in database_name. However, when I add a table, caravel identifies all the columns as UNKNOWN type. Then I look at the logs posted by caravel and the above mentioned error is logged.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved via this commit https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/commit/896fa9549ecbf5b270974f53eaf2684c4e30002e